# Clusters are too wide in comparison with distance between nodes

Tags: graphviz, dot

Consider the following dot code:

```
digraph "f400aee5-0667-4256-b0b1-e9a6a4dfa0f4" {
    graph [compound=true,
        newrank=true,
        ranksep=10,
        ratio=0.5,
    ];
    node [ shape=point ];
    subgraph "rank-1" {
        graph [rank=same];
        subgraph "cluster_1" {
            graph [label="some gaph label"];
            "node1-1";
        }
    }
    subgraph "rank-2" {
        graph [rank=same];
        "vm";
    }
    "vm" -> "node1-1";
    "vm" -> "node2-1";
    "vm" -> "node2-2";
}
```

The output of the command

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/dump1.dot | ./dot.exe -Tpng > ~/Desktop/dump1.png
```

is

[image]

The width of the cluster is unnaturally large. The ranksep is set to 10 on purpose, to create more space. But how can I make sure the width of the cluster is more in propertion with the distance between the other nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ratio`, you scale every part of the graph including the cluster. I looks like you only want to increase the distance between the lower three nodes, you can use `nodesep` for that.

Replacing `ratio=0.5` with `nodesep=5` results in the following graph:
[image]
Does this output resemble what you are looking for?

Comment: The ratio is a constant given by the application viewport aspect ratio, usually around 0.5. Setting the nodesep to a fixed constant doesn't scale up to larger graphs, does it?

Comment: The `ratio=0.5` is causing the cluster to be that wide, so to prevent that you need something else to scale up the graph. Setting a fixed constant `nodesep` might not be the best solution, but your `ranksep` is also a fixed constant. Have you tried the graph attribute `dpi`? If you set it higher than the default 96 you can increase the size of your output as well.